# Android Studio xml object over object

Tags: android, xml, textview, numbers, display

how can a put a TextView befor a Button in xml file? My textview always behind the button. I am in a constraintlayout. I want to make a little number in the top right corner of the button. I made a drawable for that, hat it looks nice.
It would be nice if someone could help! Thanks!!!

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="at.kessapps.cookieclicker.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clicker_discount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/sale_corner"
        android:text="20%"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/shopbutton"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/shopbutton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/shopbutton" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.508"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/cooltext348859404219232" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shopbutton"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
        android:onClick="toShop"
        android:text="Shop"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_store"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_neutral_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/onOption"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:onClick="toOption"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/optionen" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[here a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLgDv.png)

Comment: can you share your xml layout?

Comment: ok, i will do it

Comment: The Textview at the beginning schuld be before the Button.

Comment: please check my answer below. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this layout to put the **TextView** on top of **Button** view:

You need to add `android:translationZ="10dp"` in **TextView**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="at.kessapps.cookieclicker.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clicker_discount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:translationZ="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sale_corner"
        android:text="20%"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/shopbutton"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/shopbutton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/shopbutton" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.508"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/cooltext348859404219232" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shopbutton"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
        android:onClick="toShop"
        android:text="Shop"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_store"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_neutral_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/onOption"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:onClick="toOption"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/optionen" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```